# GIMP 2.10.18 in Ubuntu 20.04 unable to maximize screen

Tags: 20.04, gimp

The issue is as the title says. After installing gimp I can only close or minimize, but I can't modify the screen size. I'm using a new installation of ubuntu 20, was using 18 before without issues.

Is it fixable or should I revert to 18?

Comment: Ubuntu desktop & server release use a *yy.mm* format, specialist *snap* based releases use *yy* format, but they don't by default have desktops (used on headless appliances/devices), and when desktops are added, being in *snap* they aren't identical. So are you talking about an IoT release? where `gimp` isn't normally used?  Gimp has been migrating to GTK3 (from GTK2) so it's changing to the newer libraries (GTK2 will be EOL as little else uses it besides `gimp` now).   I can maximize `gimp` on my desktop release, but I'm not using a *snap* based Ubuntu Core *yy* release.

Answer (score 1):

With GIMP opened:

Edit > Preferences > Interface > Window management > Restore saved window positions to default values > OK.

Restart GIMP and your maximize button will be back, with everything working. ;D

Answer (score 0):

Figure out that after resetting every setting in the interface section of preferences can reset the window and recover the maximize button. Which one, I don't know. If you are facing the same issue try with everyone of them.

Comment: Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by `KairanD` works until GIMP is closed.

The problem for me was that I have disabled toolgroups (`Edit > Preferences > Interface > Toolbox > Use tool groups`) which made GIMP too tall to fit in my window.

There are four solutions:

- (permanent) disable toolgroups (`Edit > Preferences > Interface > Toolbox > Use tool groups`)
- (permanent) disable single window mode (`Windows > Single-Window Mode`)
- (temporary, until GIMP is closed) reload any theme (`Edit > Preferences > Interface > Theme`)
- (temporary, until GIMP is closed) enable fullscreen mode (`F11` or `View > Fullscreen`)